# Redirect user to Microsoft Azure AD Login Page from ASP .NET Core API manually

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, multi-tenant

We have a multitenant Application where we store AzureAD Details for each tenant. We do not need to set up Azure AD Authentication as soon as the app is launched. So after some operations we get those details from DB and we need to configure Microsoft Azure AD login page dynamically per tenant.

We do not store any tenant's AD details in **appsettings.json**

So scenario is like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
{
    // Challenge user to log in using Microsoft AzureAD Login 

    // If passed the challenge, the user will be able to receive the users

    var users = new List<string>{ "Mike, Jhon"};

    return Ok(users);
}
```

React js app will request to get something from our API, if tenant user is not authorized, we will redirect the user to the tenant login page that they blong to.

Is it even possible? I researched a lot. I'd say I gone through every single Azure AD login page related questions. But did not find any result.

Please, be gentle and explain the way to achive this if you have any idea or practice with.

Thanks

I also tried to challenge user this way but did not work as I expected.

```
var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx43de-b3fb-efdea0768eb7/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx-efdea0768eb7&
response_type=id_token&
redirect_uri=https://localhost:7008/signin-oidc&
scope=openid&
response_mode=form_post&
state=12345&
nonce=678910");
```

I tried this way too but this request requires App Bootstrap Azure AD configuration

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: I do not think you should try to authorize users within an API. Instead, your API should return 401 (unauthorized) if the request is not authorized. And the client application should request authorization (login page) when it receives 401 from the API.

Comment: So to generate a login page on the UI side client app will need to get the `Azure AD Details` of the tenant. Not sure how secure it is going to be. @MukulKeshari

Comment: I do not think you need to store any secrets on UI, only the tenant/client ID may be needed to redirect to the correct login page

Comment: You have a `React js` client app and an asp.net core `web API`, so the normal flow is your client app control the login redirect and the web api only give a 401/403 error code to client app request, upon receiving the error code, your client app redirect to sign in page to let users sign in. To let the react app can sign in with AAD, it must use [msal.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react#libraries).

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to check the scenario in my environment:***

In my API I have given appsettings.json including secret.

```
{
    "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      "ClientId": "xxx",
      "TenantId": "xxx-f3a0cxxb0",
      "ClientSecret": "xxxxx",
      "ClientCertificates": [
      ],
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    "DownstreamApi": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
      "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    },
```

[image]

Above we get only when the app registration is done in order to add azure ad authentication.

[image]

So when I tried to access the Application ,  I can see the authorization URL in the browser:

[image]

There you get to see that only `clientId` is exposed to user who is trying to authenticate , But client secret is only taken form backend server and is not exposed in web apis(do not use in case of SPA’s)

We have

```
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Here app.UseAuthentication(); handles the authentication capabilities, where user logs in.

so you can use  app.UseAuthorization(); only in your web api middleware to to check for user accessing resources.

So if you need to authorize user for all action methods, use **`[Authorize]`** attribute to whole controller,

```
 [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

and first action method to be called can be mapped  like below in startup.cs

In my case :Index

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
              ........
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
   
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
               

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

and in case of checking for particular operations only, if some actions don’t require the user chec, you can call [Authorize] Attribute only on those methods.

In order to only access that action with validation, while calling .

```
 [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        ViewData["ApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;

        return View();
    }
```

[image]

If not do not decorate the actions with [Authorize] attribute, which doen't require validation before accessing the api.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Could you pls share the codebase in git? So I can check it closely

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2) what you are looking for?